# How do I make the navigation menu appear inside the header?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

Using the code below I am able to form a header and a container.  The navigation menu (ul/li) appears intact in the header when on a Mac.  I am on a Mac, but when I go to view the page on a windows computer the searchbox and the #other_navigation appear below the header.

I am unsure as to what's wrong here? I am pretty sure it's with the css formatting with the #boxer and the #other_navigation menu but not sure what.

HTML:

```
 <div id="nav_holder">
 <img src="/logo.png" id="logo_holder" height="50">
 <div id="navigation">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
 <li><form action="#" method="post"></li>
 <input id="boxer" type="text">
 </form>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="other_navigation">
 <ul id="other_navi_holder">
 <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
 </ul></div>
 </div>
 <div id="centering">
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 }
 #logo_holder {
 margin-left: 80px;
 float:left;
 }
 #nav_holder {
 background-color: #888888;
 height: 40px;
 min-width: 100%;
 padding: 15px 0px;
 }
 #navigation {
 float:left;
 margin-left: 33px;
 }
 ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 line-height: 40px;
 }
 li {
 display:inline;
 padding: 30px;
 }
 #centering {
 background-color: #000000;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 min-height: 500px;
 width: 700px;
 }
 #boxer {
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-left: 513px;
 width: 200px;
 height:20px;
 position:absolute;
 margin-top: -30px;
 }
 #other_navigation {
 margin-left: 280px;
 float:left;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Odd rendering mismatches between browsers and operating systems can be a sign of invalid code somewhere.  Indeed, you are missing a closing quote in `<div id="navigation>`.  Change it to `<div id="navigation">`.  Using a code validator - http://validator.w3.org/ or http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ - is a great way to easily identify these problems.

Comment: Hey, fixed that but still the same way.

Comment: Hmm.  Could you please describe your desired result a bit more clearly for me; IE which part is the header?

Comment: Sorry about the unclarity.  The header is the #nav_holder, which is holding the logo and the navigation menu.  I want all those menu options and search box to appear inside #nav_holder.

Comment: There are still some problems with your markup:  You have closed `</nav>` but you never opened one.  You have a `<form>` inside a `<ul>` but not inside a `<li>`.  (That might be OK in some doctypes, what doctype are you using?)
I'm sorry, but I can't provide any good advice until your code is fixed up.

Comment: Yikes! Sorry, I've been plugging away at this for a while and looks like I got messy.  Let me fix it and I will comment here when it's fixed.

Comment: @ariel - No problem, just do us all a favor and validate that code.  ;)

Comment: Thanks! I reviewed the code and to me it looks valid.  I am justing <!doctype html> for HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

```
#nav_holder {
position:absolute
top:0
background-color: #888888;
height: 40px;
min-width: 100%;
padding: 15px 0px;
}
#navigation {
position:absolute
top:0
#navigation {
float:left;
margin-left: 33px;
}
```

Make sure to add the

```
position:absolute
top:0
```

to both of those, though "top:0" can be anything, just make sure they're the same. For example if you want it centered, have it "top:30%"